# RSpec controller.controller_name blank after Rails 6.1 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

After upgrading to Rails 6.1, a test helper spec on RSpec 3.11.0 seems to be broken:

```
# helpers/my_helper.rb
module MyHelper
  def foobar
    controller.controller_name.to_sym
  end
end
```

My test looks like this

```
# spec/helpers/my_helper_spec.rb
describe MyHelper do
  it "foo" do
    expect(foobar).to eq(:test)
  end
end
```

and throws this error

```
  1) MyHelper foo
     Failure/Error: controller.controller_name.to_sym

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/helpers/my_helper.rb:5:in `foobar'
```

Before the upgrade on Rails 6.0, `controller.controller_name` was just set to `"test"`, but now it's `nil`.

Do I have to set a controller name now explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out whats going on, compare these two lines:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.5/actionview/lib/action_view/test_case.rb#L104

```
@controller = ActionView::TestCase::TestController.new
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.6/actionview/lib/action_view/test_case.rb#L105

```
controller_class = Class.new(ActionView::TestCase::TestController)
```

In Rails 6.1, `controller_class` is an anonymous class with no name. And because `controller.controller_name` uses the class' name, it returns `nil`. I solved it by stubbing it like this:

```
allow(controller).to receive(:controller_name).and_return("test")
```

However, the reasoning behind this decision would be interesting. Maybe they wanted tests to be more explicit what the controller name is. This is the commit that changed that line https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3ec8ddd0cf3851fd0abfc45fd430b0de19981547

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that this will fix your problem but try to add `type: :helper` to your `describe` statement:

```rb
describe MyHelper, type: :helper do
  it "foo" do
    expect(foobar).to eq(:test)
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix the problem. The spec is already marked as a helper via `RSpec.configure { |config| config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location! }`